# Unset the far right bit in a byte

Tags: bit-manipulation

How can I unset the far right set bit in the most efficient way.

For example:

For 12 (dec) = 00001100 (bin)

I want to get: 8(dec) = 00001000 (bin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I guess the following is the most efficient way of doing it:

```
i = (i - 1) & i
```